# Set thousand separator Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, styles, number-formatting

I'm triying to format the number on my report with Apache poi but it is not working, I tried :

```
c.getCellStyle().setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#.##0,00"));
```

and

```
c.getCellStyle().setDataFormat((short)BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat("#.##0,00"));
```

But they are not working,
I'd like to show it as 1.000,99 but it is showwing 1000,99

I've only found the custom option but not the numeric, is it possible to use it ?do you know how to do it work?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Create a file in Excel with the formatting in you want, read it back with Apache POI, and see what Excel opted to put into the file? (Not always the same as what it shows in the UI....)

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat("#.##0,00"). It is returning -1 (undefined) while the proper format should return 4. But I dont know what to do to get the proper format.

Comment: Don't use a built-in format then, use a custom one?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new on this, could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats should cover you

Comment: I did it and not working either c.getCellStyle().setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#.##0,00"));

Comment: `Apache POI` creates files how `Excel` also would storing them. And `Excel` file storage is not different for different locales. It is always `en_US`. Only the `Excel` application uses the locale settings then while opening the file. So the number format code in file storage always is `#,##0.00`. Your spain `Excel` application will then converting this to `#.##0,00` if decimal separator is comma and thousands separator is dot in your system. So `.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#,##0.00"))`.

Comment: Hi, I ddi also in this way, and not working either

Comment: Works for me. Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows your issue.

Comment: I did following this example :
https://github.com/callicoder/java-read-write-excel-file-using-apache-poi
I tried modiying it but not working either

Comment: I'm working with 4.1.2 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. This is my solution :

```
   DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#,##0.00"));
...
    Cell c = row.createCell(cellDynamicNum);
    c.setCellStyle(style);
```